# Stop word list using CONTAINSTABLE

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, stop-words

Full Text search with Sql server.
We can avoid searching for Stop words using FREETEXTTABLE.
But if I search using CONTAINSTABLE, the stop words are also getting searched.

I think CONTAINS TABLE does not take into consideration the stop word list.

What is the workaround for this, if I want to avoid the stop words from getting searched in CONTAINSTABLE.

Comment: Can you show the script? Did you try to specify language? Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187914(v=sql.110).aspx